# Checking if text is NOT displayed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, webdriver

I'm currently writing unit tests in Selenium (C#). I need to do two things in this particular test:

> Check if 2 errors (with html container) are displayed **and** check if another (given) error is **not** displayed.

The test looks like this:

```
bool errorWindowVisible = tmethods.IsElementVisible(driver, By.XPath("//div[@class='message error']"));
if (errorWindowVisible == false)
{
  Assert.Fail("No error notification displayed.");
}

string errorTextTemp = "Error 1 text";
bool productIssue = tmethods.IsElementVisible(driver, By.XPath("//*[contains(.,'" + errorTextTemp + "')]"));
errorTextTemp = "Error 2 text";
bool productIssueB = tmethods.IsElementVisible(driver, By.XPath("//*[contains(.,'" + errorTextTemp + "')]"));
if (productIssue == false || productIssueB == false)
{
  Assert.Fail("No information about error cause.");
}

// Checking if another one is not visible
errorTextTemp = "Extra error";
bool uploadedFileIssue = tmethods.IsElementNotVisible(driver, By.XPath("//*[contains(.,'" + errorTextTemp + "')]"));    
if (uploadedFileIssue == false) // Should be set to true
{
  Assert.Fail("Extra error shown.");
}
```

I use two methods here:

```
public bool IsElementVisible(IWebDriver driver, By element)
{
    if (driver.FindElements(element).Count > 0)
    {
    if (driver.FindElement(element).Displayed)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}

public bool IsElementNotVisible(IWebDriver driver, By element)
{
    if (driver.FindElements(element).Count > 0)
    {
    if (driver.FindElement(element).Displayed)
        return false;
    else
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
    return true;
    }
}
```

So, all of that is working, but I am not sure about quality of that code.
On the other hand, I don't need anything over-fancy. It just should be good, clean and understandable.

Should I keep it intact or update some parts?

Comment: one thing.when you have `tmethods.IsElementVisible` dont create `tmethods.IsElementNotVisible`. just negate and write `!tmethods.IsElementVisible`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `IsElementVisible` method can be condensed to:

```
public bool IsElementVisible(IWebDriver driver, By element)
{
    return driver.FindElements(element).Count > 0
        && driver.FindElement(element).Displayed;
}
```

I guess the method `IsElementNotVisible` should return boolean negation of result of the `IsElementVisible` method:

```
public bool IsElementNotVisible(IWebDriver driver, By element)
{
    return !IsElementVisible(driver, element);
}
```

---

#### Boolean comparisons

Expressions `x == true` and just `x` are eqivalent.
Expressions `x == false` and just `!x` are also eqivalent.
For example, you don't need to write:

```
if (productIssue == false || productIssueB == false)
```

you could write instead:

```
if (!productIssue || !productIssueB)
```

Comment: Question about IsElementVisible - why do we count that elements and check if are displayed? Count is faster so when it fails it doesn't bother to check if element is displayed, or there is another reason for that 2 conditions?

Comment: @BlackHat Is this question for me? You should answer it, because it is your code. I've just simplified it. I don't even know what the type `IWebDriver` is.

Comment: A bit embarrassing... I totally forgot about origin of that code. Funny thing now I am not sure why have I implemented that way. Sorry for the fuss!

Answer (score 8):

### Test review

It is not clear from the code in your upper code block, whether you are doing three separate tests, or if that is one test method doing three assertions.

Anyway it is common to strive for that *one test method has only one assertion*. Having multiple tests in one test method is considered a bad test regime.

Using `Assert.Fail()` is also somewhat uncommon. It would be better to use `Assert.IsTrue()` or `Assert.IsFalse()` and move the condition into the actual assert.

Finally, regarding the assertions, I'm not thrilled about your texts. What information do you get from "Extra error shown" or "Error 1 text"? Let the test cases and texts be clear and informative, so that you know what actions to take if it fails at some point in time.

### Style review

First of all, [Dmitry](//codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39186/dmitry) has some excellent point regarding refactoring in [his answer](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/108324/78136). My comments are more on the existing code in your lower block:

- *Don't mix brace styles* – In some cases you have braces around the `if` blocks, and some places you don't. You are much better off using braces always! Even though some consider this a disease, braceophilia, you will save yourself time and trouble always including the braces
- *Clean up indentation of your code* – Your code is very confusing when looking at the indentation. This is both a reason for you to include braces (which would clearly indicate blocks), and it will (with a decent editor) help you get the indentation correct.

  As it stands, it is confusing which level of the `if` statement the `Count` and/or `Displayed` statements are at. They should be at distinct indentation levels.
- *Avoid negated functions* – There is a reason why the `!` operator exists, and duplicating your logic like you've done is a code smell.  Keep one of them, and make that one correct and efficient, and use the `!` operator to get the opposite version. (Or in some rare cases include the negated version, but let it call the ordinary version (as suggested by Dmitry))
- *Don't use `if` blocks to return the condition* – This is already covered by Dmitry, but instead of doing `if (someCondition) { return true; } else { return false; }`, simplify it to `return someCondition;`

Comment: `braceophilia` got me laughing ;-)

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, I've removed all issues you mentioned. Also small comment: I don't use error slogans like "Error 1 text", but I had to censor them due to my company restrictions :) Thanks again!